# Custom *ML like FBML

Tags: xml, markup

Can anyone tell me how can I make my own Markup Language like Facebook' FBML?

I was searching on the net but all I can find is that I can make markup language using XML and DTD.

Comment: Yep, that's it. The markup language is the syntax, the semantics is up to you... And I'd add XSD to this.

Comment: But can you point me to some reference where I can find more about making it.

Comment: Any book with a title like "Introducing XML" or "XML for beginners" should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it. Here:

```
<language>
  <name>My markup language</name>
  <example>See above</example>
</language>
```

I've just done it. Of course, depending how you want to use it, you will have to document it and define it to make it usable; and if you want applications to be able to understand it then you will have to write those applications; and you may want to write a schema or DTD to distinguish documents that use your markup language correctly from those that don't.